# how to separate 'xml' tag from a given String

Tags: java, xml, apache, http

I am new comer to rest API and I try to read `xml` tags in a restful API using Apache http .In here I've got all the `xml` tags together , but actually I want to get it as tag based . Which like following

```
<xml>something</xml>
```

This is my `ClientProtocol` class which is used to read restful API .

```
package web;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class ClientProtocal
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try
        {
            HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet("https://xxxxredddd");
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGetRequest);

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(httpResponse.getStatusLine());
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            if (entity != null)
            {
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                try
                {
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
                    while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) != -1)
                    {
                        String chunk = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        System.out.println(chunk);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally
                {
                    try
                    {
                        inputStream.close();
                    } catch (Exception ignore)
                    {
                        ignore.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally
        {
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of string do you receive back from the server? Perhaps using a SAX like XML parser is approriate

Comment: You use an XML parser to read the input stream, parse it, and get particular data items from it. Here is one [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/) for you.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thank you for the massive help .

Comment: @AndreSchild It just give me all the xml tags together . like a paragraph